# ld: Warning: error adding Flurry to iPhone project

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I've attempted to add Flurry analytics to my app project.  It is driving me nuts.  The app has logged some user data on a few occasions.  On others however I get a link warning when I build the app.  When that happens, it seems like it isn't logging the analytics.  I don't know what to do.  I move around the FlurryLib file and sometimes the error disappears. Then without changing anything, the error comes back.

What causes a Link warning?
Is it possible that this error is what is keeping Flurry from logging analytics?
How can I fix it?

My biggest concern is that the error reads a directory that doesn't exist.  It's looking for the files in the wrong folder.  I once had the files in my dropbox (not doing that again) and now I have them on my desktop.  It's still "looking" for the files in my dropbox - if I'm reading this right.  I think its attempting to link to files that are located in a different place.

Here is the link warning copied and (edited slightly):

ld: warning: directory '/Users/mbp/Desktop/Game Projects/WWTBTH 01-12/../../../../Development/Game Development/Trivia Game/WWTBTH 08-06/FlurryLib' following -L not found

Why is it jumping to the development folder in my dropbox that the file isn't in anymore?  In an archive (08-06) when its located in the (01-12) folder on my desktop?

Here are the other 5 warnings:

ld: warning: directory '/Users/mbp/Desktop/Game Projects/WWTBTH 01-12/../../../../Downloads/Flurry iPhone SDK v2.7 (2)/iPhone v2.7 (build 42)/FlurryLib' following -L not found

ld: warning: directory '/Users/mbp/Desktop/Game Projects/WWTBTH 01-12/../../../../Development/Game Development/Trivia Game/WWTBTH 08-06/Flurry iPhone SDK v2/iPhone v2.7 (build 42)/FlurryLib' following -L not found

ld: warning: directory '/Users/mbp/Desktop/Game Projects/WWTBTH 01-12/FlurryLib' following -L not found

ld: warning: directory '/Users/mbp/Desktop/Game Projects/WWTBTH 01-12/../../../../Development/Game Development/Trivia Game/WWTBTH 08-06/Flurry iPhone SDK v2.7/iPhone v2.7 (build 42)/FlurryLib' following -L not found

ld: warning: directory '/Users/mbp/Desktop/Game Projects/WWTBTH 01-12/../../../../Development/Game Development/Trivia Game/WWTBTH 08-06/Flurry iPhone SDK v2.7/iPhone v2.7 (build 42)/FlurryLibWithLocation' following -L not found

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue with my app with another library. What I did was go under "Search Paths" and "Library Search Paths" and i removed the library that was giving me the warning. I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this warning the other day.  I forget what the specific property was, but it's definitely in the build settings for your project.  Xcode has added the now non-existent directory to the paths the linker looks for libs.  Just go in there and remove that property.  This might not fix your flury analytics not working problem, but it will clear up that warning.

Comment: Any guesses what that property could be named? Or what is currently in the property?